# Steam API check in DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql, api, steam

I have a *Steam API* created and working well.

The Database table is:

```
DB: Steam_users
tables: id, steamid, name, avatar, credits
```

My question is: **How can I get a value from the table like "*Credits*" using the *SESSION* from the user *steamID*?**

Like:

```
print $_SESSION['user']['credits'];
```

But for *Steam API* I can't understand how can I do it.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What do you mean by 'I have a SteamAPI created and working well'?

Comment: You talk about the API and the database. This is your database, I assume? What about this "Steam API". It's something you wrote, or it's an official API run by Steam? You ask how to get a value from the database. Then you say "but for Steam API I can't understand how do it". Where do you want to get the data from - the API or the database? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Ok, Steam Sessions no work with Cookies... That's why i am asking how can i get a value from the USER in SESSION in the DB.

Comment: @John that comment doesn't answer any of the questions that either Tomasz or I asked you...

Comment: Guys... let me explain...
I've a php script that sincronize with Steam... calls OpenID.... ok...
That script runs a code that inserts the users data, example... SteamID, SteamName, Steam Avatar etc... to the table.. right...

But now...in the table i create another colunm that calls Credits... So...
I wanna show that collum in the Session from the USER...

So.. if the user is JOHN and he have 10 Credits, show the 10 creditos...

Comment: ok so post the code you've done so far. Which part are you having trouble with? Querying the database? Showing it on the page? And where does the session come into it? Please edit the question with some existing code and more context.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the official SteamWebAPI there is no entry to get "steam credit". What is credit supposed to be? The money value of the steam wallet of the user? I do not think that that information is available publicly.

The documentation of the SteamWebAPI might help you get what you need: https://wiki.teamfortress.com/w/index.php?title=WebAPI&redirect=no